# Using Pandas Series, Numpy Arrays and Python Lists efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

**The task**: I have a a series of daily closing stock prices and I want to achieve the following:
(i) Compute maximum percentage change between any two days within any 5-day window
(ii) Store these maximums on a 5-day rolling window basis
(iii) Compute 99th percentile of these maximums over all 5-day rolling windows

Fairly simple problem. I am quite new to Python and have found myself mixing a Python list, a Numpy array and Pandas Series to achieve the above, which I am sure is not the right way to code efficiently.

**The question**: I attach my code below. Is there a way to achieve the same objective without having to use multiple objects for this simple task (i.e. a Pandas DataFrame, which is then copied into a Numpy Array, which is used to amend a Python list, which in the end is converted to a Pandas Series)? Also, can the inner loop be achieved via native Numpy or Pandas iterating method (such as ndenumerate), rather than looping via indexing?

```
#pd_prices is a Pandas DataFrame containing daily open, high, low, and close prices

#store just closing prices into a Numpy array
np_prices = np.array(pd_prices['close'])

my_max = [0] # Python list that will be appended

# loop through Numpy array using ndenumerate
for i, price in np.ndenumerate(np_prices):

    local_max = 0.0
    j = min(i[0],(np_prices.size - 6))
    for k in range(1,6,1):
        # compute local % change between two days within a 5-day window
        pct_change = (np_prices[j+k] / np_prices[j]) - 1
        # store max over the current 5-day window 
        local_max = max(local_max,abs(pct_change))

     # save max from current 5-day window into  list before computing max over next 5-day window
     my_max.append(local_max)

#in order to use Pandas quantile function, the list is converted to Pandas Series object
pd_maxes = pd.Series(my_max)
print(pd_maxes.quantile(0.99))
```

Comment: could you give a little bit more information about dimensionality? `np_prices` and `my_max` are how large? You could most definitely just all do it in `numpy` with `np.quantile(my_max, .99, axis=?)`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mad Physicist: will closing translate into removing, or just closing to further discussion?

Comment: @MadPhysicist While this may be on-topic on CR in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *needs focus* (as I have done here), *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: A question being closed, on the technical side, means it will become impossible to post new answers, and it becomes possible for users with 10,000 or more reputation to delete it after a few days. It will not, by itself, lead to the question being removed.

Comment: I've amended the question to try to make it more focused. In any way, Dorian below provided a very helpful answer. I am not trying to achieve a code review here, but I am trying to learn Numpy and Pandas properly: i.e. to learn how to code in the most efficient way: so hopefully the question can be viewed as useful for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggenstions:

1. create `numpy` array from list:

   `my_max = np.vstack(my_max)`
   potentially hstack, not sure about the dimensionality
2. use `numpy` also for quantiles:

   `print(np.quantile(my_max, 0.99, axis=?)`
   again, axis not sure about the underlying data`
3. if you want to get of the python list and the `stack` function from `numpy`, and you know the size of your array beforehand, go with:

   `my_max = np.empty((rows, cols))`

just make sure you actually initialize them, of use `np.zeros`, depending on your data.

Edit (regarding your comment):

4. if you want to divide each element by either the next, second next ... and so on, use vectorization:

   `div = array[:-1] / array[1:]`

   this divides each element by the next, except for the last, since it's not possible there. if you want to do this for, say, the fifth element, shift the index by 5:

   `div = array[:-5] / array[5:]`

   you can either write this 5 times or use a loop to loop over that parameter n, however, this is far quicker that 2 nested loops, cause its using numpys internal vectorization.

Comment: Thanks so much! One more question if I may: I have been told in another post that I shouldn't iterate through Numpy array via indexing, but rather via the np.ndenumerate method. But what about the inner loop where I need to gradually compute percentage returns over: array[j] / array[j+k]  where k goes from 1 to 5. It seems the most efficient way to iterate here is just via direct indexing and only use np.ndenumerate on the outer loop?